# Autotmatically renewing locks correctly on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

So I'm trying to understand service bus timings - especially how the locks works. One can choose to manually call `CompleteAsync` which is what we're doing. It could also be the case that the processing takes some time. In these cases we want to make sure we don't get unnecessary `MessageLockLostException`.

Seems there are a couple of numbers to relate to:

- Lock duration (found in Azure Portal on the Service Bus, currently set to 1 minute which is think is default)
- `AutoRenewTimeout` (property on `OnMessageOptions`, currently set to 1 minute)
- `AutoComplete` (property on `OnMessageOptions`, currently set to false)

Assuming the message processing is running for around 2 minutes, and then either succeeds or crashes (doesn't matter which case for now). Let's say this is the normal scenario, so this means that processing takes roughly 2 minutes for each message.

Also, it's indeed a queue and not a topic. And we only have one consumer that asynchronously processes the messages with `MaxConcurrentCalls` set to 100. We're using `OnMessageAsync` with `ReceiveMode.PeekLock`.

What should my settings now be as a single consumer to robustly process all messages?

I'm thinking that leaving Lock duration to 1 minute would be fine, as that's the default, and set my `AutoRenewTimeout` to 5 minutes for safety, because as I've understood this value should be the maximum time it takes to process a message ([at least according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36589348/2874896)). Performance is not critical for this system, so I'm resonating as that leaving a message locked for some unnecessary 1, 2 or 3 minutes is not evil, as long as we don't get `LockedException` because these give no real value.

[This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d3b99f5a-a717-4175-9f75-697739ae737f/renew-brokeredmessage-lock-duration?forum=servbus) and [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/069653b5-c233-4942-85b2-9eb50b3865c7/azure-service-bus-subscription-how-do-i-delete-the-message-when-i-receive-a?forum=servbus) gives great examples of how to manually renew the locks, but I thought there is a way to automatically renew the locks.

Comment: Check out the [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.IMessageSession.RenewSessionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.imessagesession.renewsessionlockasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_IMessageSession_RenewSessionLockAsync) method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What should my settings now be as a single consumer to robustly process all messages?

Aside from `LockDuration`, `MaxConcurrentCalls`, `AutoRenewTimeout` and `AutoComplete`, there are some configurations of the Azure Service Bus client you might want to look into.

For example, don't create a single client with `MaxConcurrentCalls` set to 100, but create multiple clients with total concurrency level distributed among them. Note that you'd want to use **different** `MessagingFactory` instances to create those clients to ensure you have more than a single "pipe" to receive messages. And even with that, it would be way better to scale out and have competing consumers rather than having a single consumer handling all the load.

Now back to the settings. If your normal processing time is 2 minutes, it's better to set `MaxLockDuration` on the entities to this time and not 1 minute. This will remove unnecessary lock extension calls to the broker and eliminate `MessageLockLostException`.

Also, keep in mind that `AutoRenewTimeout` operation is based on the client, not the broker, and therefore not guaranteed. You will run into cases where lock will be lost even though the `AutoRenewTimeout` time has not elapsed yet.

`AutoRenewTimeout` should always be set to longer than `MaxLockDuration` as it will be counterproductive to have them equal. Have it somewhat larger than `MaxLockDuration` as this is clients' "insurance" that when processing takes longer than `MaxLockDuration`, message lock won't be lost. Having those two equal is, in essence, disables this fallback.

Comment: Good tips! Where do you find `MaxLockDuration`? What we did was to increase the `LockDuration ` on the queue to 2 minutes and set `AutoRenewTimeout` to 2 minutes as well.

Comment: Also - you essentially mean multiple calls to `QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString` in order to get different `MessagingFactory` and then create different clients from there on? Sounds rather complicated, but maybe that's the truly robust solution.

Comment: @JimAho `MaxLockDuration` would be on the queues/subscriptions you create. I would not set `AutoRenewTimeout` to two minutes as it defeats the purpose of the setting. Have it somewhat larger than `MaxLockDuration` as this is our sort of "insurance" that when processing takes longer than two minutes, message lock won't be lost. Having those two equal is in essense disables this fallback.

Comment: For the multiple clients is not enough to be created with the same `QueueClient`, you have to go through a different messaging factory. If load is not significant, you might thing of this as optional. _And_ if I answered your quesion, do you mind to indicate so? Thanks :)

Comment: When you refer to `MaxLockDuration` you mean just `LockDuration`? I cannot find it otherwise.

Comment: I've accepted, feel free to update it and include your motivation regarding `AutoRenewTimeout` as I found that very helpful too. The fact that you do not recommend setting it to the same as `LockDuration`.

Comment: Even though problem was solved, gotta tell you guys that `messageReceiver.RenewLockAsync(message);` solved the problem for me. Make sure you don't enter infinite loop there and renew your lock at proper point of execution.